# CKEDITOR - Texto Pré-Definido

Tags: php, ckeditor

Alguém tem alguma ideia de onde eu posso estar colocando um texto pré-definido dentro do `textarea?`

Exemplo na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dentro do próprio `textarea`. Ex.: `<textarea>texto pré definido</textarea>`

Comment: Como eu não pensei nisso antes? Valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode pré-definir um texto simplesmente adicionando-o no `textarea`, inclusive com tags HTML, pois quando o CKEditor renderiza-lo, as tags também serão aplicadas:

```
<textarea id="editor"><b>texto em negrito</b></textarea>
```

Outra forma de inserir um texto é através da API do plugin, usando `.setData()`:

```
var pre_texto = "<b>texto em negrito</b>";
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData(pre_texto);
```